# Access to IPv4 CIDR of a subnet passed as parameter in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm passing as a parameter a "Subnet ID"

```
  VPCPrivateSubnet1:
    Description: VPCPrivateSubnet1
    Type: String
    Default: 'subnet-83733e21'
```

Then, I'm creating a "Security Group"

```
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPCid
      GroupDescription: Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 10
        ToPort: 10
        CidrIp: ???
```

And for the **CidrIp** I would like to have a way to refer to it without having to type it. Something like `VPCPrivateSubnet1.CidrIp`. I don't have the Subnet exported (so I can import it). I am not creating it in the template, so I cannot use Ref.

I will appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not easily achievable. But even if you had your subnet defined in the same template as your security group, or exported from other stack, [AWS::EC2::Subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#aws-resource-ec2-subnet-return-values) **can't return its CIDR**.

However, you could design [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation which would give you the CIDR of a subnet you want.

For this you would have to write your own custom lambda function, which would take the subnet's id and using, e.g., boto3 SDK, return the CIDR into CloudFormation.

Having this you could do `!GetAtt CustomGetSubnetInfoResource.CidrIp`, where `CustomGetSubnetInfoResource` could be the name of your custom resource.

Comment: @Peter No problem. As a side note, you can get the CIDR of a VPC from its [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html#aws-resource-ec2-vpc-return-values). Wish same was true for subnet.